# Auto scaling disable for indicators in trading view chart pine editor

Tags: pivot, pine-script, indicator

I trade using Pivot Points. I use the following on screen indicators indicators “CM_Pivots_Filtered”, “Pivots”, “CD_PivotR” and “CM_Gaps_Intra-Day_V2.1” These pivots work perfectly.

However, when I deploy them all and the Auto Scale button is switch on; because of this I am unable to see Price Action. This is because Auto Scale also wants to fit in all the Pivot Levels. However, Auto Scale does not exhibit the same behavior for other on screen indicators like Bollinger Bands, Ichimoku, VPSV etc. The script of the above mentioned indicators in available and editable. What command/script I copy and add to the pine editor program so that, Auto Scale does try to fit all the Pivot Levels.

In short, I want Auto Scale to only work on price action, nothing else.

[image]

Comment: It seems like a feature-request for me. You should create a ticket on tridingview website. There you can describe what you wish. Here we unable to help you with that. SO is the place where developers give a hand to another developers, who encounter some troubles with their code.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it helps but you can click on the scaling settings (cog wheel in the bottom right corner) and select **Scale Price chart Only**

[image: Screenshot of scaling options]

Comment: Is there a way to do this for indicators that aren’t on the price line? Things like an RSI that belong in their own plot, but you may have other plots to exclude on the section because they would blow out the scaling.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Better to open a new question and attach a picture.